# Can't extract gz file using the patool package

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, gzip

I am trying to use the [`patool`](https://pypi.org/project/patool/) package to perform a simple operation: decompressing a `gz` archive that consists of one file. This one file in the archive is and xml file that has exactly the same name as the archive, just without the `.gz` ending.

The code I use for this is:

```
import patoolib
filePath = 'D:\\inpath\\file.xml.gz'
outPath= 'D:\\outpath'
patoolib.extract_archive(filePath,outdir=outPath, interactive=False, verbosity=-1)
```

But what happens is that the file is being extracted but in a corrupt manner. That is, the file appears in the `outPath` folder, but has 0kb and cannot be opened. The error I get is:

> PatoolError: Command `['c:\Rtools\bin\gzip.EXE', '-c', '-d', '--', 'D:\inpath\file.xml.gz', '>', 'D:\outPath\file.xml']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Now, I am certain that the archive is not corrupt, since when I perform the extraction manually using Windows Explorer, it does work properly.

This code did work for some other files, but I can't understand why this is occurring for this file. Also, I am wondering whether there is perhaps a simpler way of doing this that is known o work more smoothly.

Comment: 1) can you provide a file example or it is too big? is it downloadable from internet? 2) maybe try increase verbosity - see what the error messages are 3) once it works on command line, maybe do a command line call with `subprocess`. or even just leave the command in bash/batch file?

Comment: Also why not https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress?